# Validacion de formulario para registro de persona en base de datos con python

Tags: python

Gente espero que puedan ayudarme con este tema que me esta presentado al realizar la validacion de formulario para el registro de persona en una base de datos.

en el formulario como que no me reconoce los input porque no me imprime el msj error que coloco en el validador, cuando le doy enter sin colocar ninguna letra ni caracter. Ejemplo:(if datosFinales["nombre"]=='':
errores["nombre"]='campo nombre vacio').

otro error que tengo es que al ingresar todo los datos del input en el formulario me da un error en la clase de validación exactamente me dice error de llave KeyError'constraseña', no logro finiquitar el registro.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user="root",
password="23640183",
database="proyectopoo"
)
cursor=mydb.cursor()

dbconfi={
'host':"localhost",
'user':"root",
'password':"23640183",
'database':"proyectopoo"
}

class db():
def __init__(self):
    self.conexion=mysql.connector.connect(**dbconfi)
    self.cursor=self.conexion.cursor()
    self.commit=self.conexion.commit()

def get_cursor(self):
    return self.cursor
def get_commit(self):
    return self.commit
def get_conexion(self):
    return self.conexion
dba=db()



from dba import dba
```

from validate_email import validate_email

class Validator():
def **init**(self):
pass

```
def vali_usuario(self,dic):
    datosFinales={}
    errores={}
    SpecialSym=['$','@','#','%','-','_']
    for x,y in dic.items():
        datosFinales[x]=y.strip()

    if datosFinales["nombre"]=='':
        errores["nombre"]='campo nombre vacio'
    if datosFinales["apellido"]=='':
        errores["apellido"]='campo apellido vacio'
        
    if datosFinales["email"]=='':
        errores["email"]="campo email vacio"
    elif validate_email(datosFinales["email"])==False:
        errores["email"]="el mail no es correcto"
    """elif db.buscar_usuario(datosFinales['email']) != None:
        errores['email']='el mail esta en uso'"""
    if datosFinales["celular"]=='':
        errores["celular"]='campo celular vacio'
    
    if len(datosFinales["contraseña"])< 4:
        errores["contraseña"]='la contraseña debe tener mas de 2 caracteres'
    if datosFinales["contraseña"]=='':
        errores["contraseña"]='la clave esta vacia'
    elif not any(char.isdigit()for char in datosFinales ["contraseña"]):
        errores["contraseña"]='la clave debe tener al menos un numeral'
    elif not any(char.isupper()for char in datosFinales ["contraseña"]):
        errores["contraseña"]='la clave debe tener al menos una mayuscula'
    elif not any(char.islower()for char in datosFinales ["contraseña"]):
        errores["contraseña"]='la clave debe tener al menos una minuscula'
    elif not any(char in SpecialSym for char in datosFinales ["contraseña"]):
        errores["contraseña"]='la clave debe tener al menos un $#%@'


    if errores=={}:
        sql="SELECT id from usuario where email=%s"
        val=(datosFinales['email'],)
        dba.get_cursor().execute(sql,val)
        resultado=dba.get_cursor().fetchone()
        if resultado is not None:
            errores['email']='el correo ya esta registrado'
            return errores
    return errores
```

validator=Validator()

```
formusuario={}
formusuario['nombre']=input('escriba el nombre del usuario: ')
formusuario['apellido']=input('escriba el apellido del usuario: ')
formusuario['email']=input('escriba el email del usuario: ')
formusuario['celular']=input('escriba el celular del usuario: ')

formusuario['ncontraseña']=input('escriba de nuevo la contraseña')

if validator.vali_usuario(formusuario)=={}:
usu=Usuario(formusuario['nombre'],formusuario['apellido'],formusuario['email'],formusuario['celular']
,formusuario['id_pais'],formusuario['contraseña'],formusuario[''])
usu.save()
print('registro exitoso')
```

else:
print(validator.vali_usuario(formusuario))

adjunto pastebin como segunto metodo de vista para la ayuda

https://pastebin.com/WYi9sFr1

Answer (score 0):

debido a mi reputacion no puedo comentar. Aun asi creo que esto puede considerarse respuesta.
Miré tu codigo en la función `vali_usuario`, y me di cuenta de que creas el diccionario `datosFinales`, que está vacio.
En la linea `datosFinales["nombre"]==''` estás consultando un diccionario vacio. Y como la clave que le pasas no existe, te envia un error.

Espero que lo que te dije sirva y bienvenido a StackOverflow c: